# List comprehension - concatenate nth item from each sub-list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

The idea is to do concatenate of nth item from sub-list as below. Here I would like to automate such a way that I don't need to define each ol[0] or ol[1] manually each time depending upon length of the original list i.e ol; Any possibility?

For example, if my input list is:

```
[("a","b","c"),("A","B","C")]
```

the desired result is as:

```
['aA', 'bB', 'cC']
```

---

Here's my current code to perform this:

```
ol = [("a","b","c"),("A","B","C")]

x=None
y=None

nL=[(x+y) for x in ol[0] for y in ol[1] if ol[0].index(x)==ol[1].index(y)]
print(nL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`zip()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to achieve this as:

```
>>> ol = [("a","b","c"),("A","B","C")]

#                                 v to unpack the list
>>> nL = [''.join(x) for x in zip(*ol)]

# OR explicitly concatenate elements at each index
# >>> nL = [a+b for a, b in zip(*ol)]

>>> nL
['aA', 'bB', 'cC']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use builtin `zip()` function (this example is using f-string for concatenating the strings inside the lists):

```
ol=[("a","b","c"),("A","B","C")]
print([f'{a}{b}' for a, b in zip(*ol)])
```

Output:

```
['aA', 'bB', 'cC']
```

The asterisk `*` in the `zip` will expands the iterable, so you don't have to index it by hand.

To make it universal and concatenate multiple values, you can use this script:

```
ol=[("a","b","c"),("A","B","C"), (1, 2, 3), ('!', '@', '#')]
print([('{}' * len(ol)).format(*v) for v in zip(*ol)])
```

Will print:

```
['aA1!', 'bB2@', 'cC3#']
```